# Is there a grammatical mistake in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

I just spotted a sentence in a magazine article, Which seems to have a grammatical mistake. Please find it as follows. It seems that the subject is missing, isn't it? There should be a noun before *is* in the sentence; no? Thanks!

> Within the vast collection of the National Museum of Fine Arts of
>   Havana is an astonishing breadth of work by some of Cuba’s greatest
>   artists.

Comment: Which magazine? Can you provide a link to an online version?

Comment: (the first sentence in this article) http://artasiapacific.com/Blog/TheNatureOfAbstractionInterviewWithCarlosGarcADeLaNuez

Comment: It has subject-dependent inversion. The basic uninverted version would be _An astonishing breadth of work by some of Cuba’s greatest artists is within the vast collection of the National Museum of Fine Arts of Havana_. Now you can see that the subject is _An astonishing breadth of work by some of Cuba’s greatest artists_, and the predicate is _is within the vast collection of the National Museum of Fine Arts of Havana_. The sequence beginning "within ..." is the dependent, a preposition phrase functioning as a preposed locative complement in your example..

Comment: Got it! Thanks BillJ and user69786's explanations! So may I further ask what feelings this kind of reverse narrative would bring out, e.g., poetic and elegant, in comparison with the normal SVO narrative? (Just wanna know when would be suitable to use this inverted narrative) Thanks!

Comment: Usually, a preposed complement serves as a link to the preceding discourse, i.e. it would be closely related to information previously mentioned.

Comment: It’s not very elegantly worded, though. It’s a bit clumsy to speak of a breadth of work _being within_ a museum. You’d normally say the museum houses/holds/contains an astonishing breadth of work, or that the breadth of work is housed/held/something’ed (with)in the museum. You could even just say that the breadth of work is within the museum. But there’s something jarring about the plain _is_ and the preposition _within_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Maybe, but that was the sentence as it was presented to us. The OP was not looking for a revision, but simply an explanation of the grammar. No point in nit-picking and obscuring the answer the OP was looking for.

Comment: @BillJ That’s why I left it as a comment, rather than an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the grammar is perfectly fine. The subject is ***an astonishing breadth of work by some of Cuba's greatest artists*** and the predicate is ***Within the vast collection of the National Museum of Fine Arts of Havana is***. The order is just reversed. This is not a super common grammar patter in English, but you will definitely see it from time to time. Mainly in the written word. This is primarily a narrative-style type of grammar common in literature and news article writing.

Example:

> Among the country leaders who were preset at the parade was the President of Latvia.

The same sentence rewritten using the normal word order:

> The President of Latvia was among the country leaders who were present at the parade.

Comment: yes, except president is lowercase.

Answer (score -2):

I somehow do not agree with accepted answer, I would say below is correct sentence or may better sentence:

Within the vast collection of the National Museum of Fine Arts of Havana **, there** is an astonishing breadth of work by some of Cuba’s greatest artists.

Comment: It is always good if people also point out reason for down voting

Comment: Excuse me but "below is correct sentence" or "may better sentence" are not idiomatic. Therefore, how can you tell if the accepted answer is correct?

Comment: @Lambie Didn't you read that I have clearly mentioned in the start that "I somehow do not agree with accepted answer", so I mentioned by my answer is a "better answer" in case if the guy insist that his answer is right.

Comment: @Lambie It would be better if you could point out mistake in the answer I have suggested.

Comment: @Lambie Fine, got it that why you became so fixated about my finger pointing on the accepted answer. Actually my intention was really not to declare the accepted answer as wrong but to propose a better sentence, may be I didn't put up my intentions properly. And if you think that my proposed answer is grammatically incorrect then please do let me know along with your explanation.

Comment: @Lambie And once this is over why don't you give me your valuable time on this question of mine - https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/471405/what-is-the-grammatical-mistake-in-this-line

Feel free to downvote it as well but if I can get my answer then it will be worth it for me.

Comment: @Lambie Looks like you did your best to my question, thanks a lot.